# How to add separate width to the each bar in barchart in recharts?

Tags: bar-chart, recharts

I am trying to plot a barchart using recharts and reactjs where I want each bar to have different width and same height. I have tried different solution but none of them worked. Please provide solution for this.

```
const data = [
   { name: "A", length: 10, width: 20, color: "red" },
   { name: "B", length: 10, width: 30, color: "green" },
   { name: "C", length: 10, width: 80, color: "blue" },
   { name: "D", length: 10, width: 10, color: "yellow" };
];
```

You may use above json to plot the barchart.